# What is an analog of WebActivator in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core

Previously (in asp.net 4.x) there was common practice to use `WebActivator` class for register bootstrap logic.
I understand that now we have `Startup` class where everything can be configured. But with `WebActivator` I had more options - it was possible to drop-in an assembly into an app (add a nuget) and the assembly registered everything it needs on its own. For this an assemble had assembly level attribute with a type which should be called:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof (ModuleBootstrapper), "Start")]
```

What is recommended approach for such things ("lib initialization") in the new glory asp.net 5 now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functionality you can get with `WebActivator` is not possible under ASP.NET 5 and I strongly believe that it won't ever be because one of the great things about ASP.NET 5 pipeline is that you are responsible building up your request pipeline. So, the decision should be deliberately made. As an example:

I have a middleware:

```
public class MonitoringMiddlware
{
    private RequestDelegate _next;

    public MonitoringMiddlware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // do some stuff on the way in

        await _next(httpContext);

        // do some stuff on the way out
    }
}
```

I can package this up and publish to a NuGet feed. Consumer needs to pull this in and add this into the appropriate place inside the pipeline:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure services here
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseFileServer();

        // I want middleware to sit here inside the pipeline.
        app.UseMiddleware<MonitoringMiddlware>();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "controllerRoute",
                "{controller}",
                new { controller = "Home" });
        });
    }
}
```

So, whenever I come into this code, I can see how the pipeline is being built without any magic. In the `WebActivator` case, you would need to look into a few other places to figure out your pipeline and most of all, you wouldn't be making the decision where it sits.

So, it was not a bad thing to get rid of it.